# python numpy log2 returns -inf when using Popen

Tags: python, numpy, subprocess

I am trying to run this line:

```
print(np.log2( (ngram_list.count(('i',)) + 1 )/( 100000 + len(set(n1gram_list)) )))
```

When I run my script from terminal I get -1.54814270552.
But when I run the same script via subprocess.Popen I get -inf.
Basically every time the output of log2 is positive I get the right output in both method but for negative values I get -inf only when using Popen.

Comment: We don't have enough of an example to verify this result. Please see [ask], then provide a [mcve]. Otherwise, your question is likely to be put on hold or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using Python 2 when using `Popen`, which uses integer division instead.

Either use `from __future__ import division`, convert `100000 + len(set(n1gram_list))` to float, or call Python 3 instead.

Comment: In Popen I run the command 'python lm.py'. When I try to run 'python3 lm.py' nothing happens. How can I run this command with python 3?